# Write to a single file from multiple reducers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, file-io, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to run Kmeans using Hadoop. I want to save the centroids of the clusters calculated in the cleanup method of the Reducer to some file say `centroids.txt`. Now, I would like to know what will happen if multiple reducers' cleanup method starts at the same time and all of them try to write to this file simultaneously. Will it be handled internally? If not is there a way to synchronize this task?

Note that this is not my output file of reducer. It is an additional file that I am maintaining to keep track of the centroids. I am using BufferedWriter from the reducer's cleanup method to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> Yes you are right. You cannot achieve that using existing framework.
>   Cleanup will be called many times.and you cannot synchronize. Possible
>   approaches you can follow are
>
> 1. Call merge after successful job.
>
>    `hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]`
>
>    [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge)
>
> 2 Clearly specify where your output file(s) should go. Use this folder as input to your next job.
>
> 3 Chain one more MR. where map and reduce don't change the data, and partitioner assigns all data to a single reducer

Answer (score 0):

Each reducer writes to a separate file. Multiple reducers can never modify the same file.

Comment: This is not the output of the reducer. I am using BufferedWriter from the Reducer to write to this additional file i.e centroids.txt.

Comment: That is not a good idea. Write a separate file from each reducer instead and do some post-processing to merge those.

Answer (score 0):

Since the centroids are relatively few you can write them into zookeeper. If you had a high read/write load you would probably need HBase (which you can also use here but it would be an overkill)

Also note that there are several k-means implementation on Hadoop like [Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-clustering.html). Some of these implementations are more efficient than map/reduce like [Apache Hama](https://blogs.apache.org/hama/entry/running_hama_k_means_in) which uses BSP or [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html) which runs in-memory

Comment: Your suggestions are good but they do not fit my situation. It's an academic project and we are not allowed to use an other framework like Zookeeper or Mahout.